# On a characterization of some subsets

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $A$ is a linear closed and densely defined operator and $S$ is a bounded invertible operator.  What' s the relation between $\sigma_{e,S}(\lambda S - A)$ and $\sigma_{e,S}(A)$? Is it true that $\sigma_{e,S}(\lambda S- A)=\sigma_{e,S}(A) +  \lambda ?$

Here $\sigma_{e,S}(A): = \{\lambda \in\mathbb{C}\,\,\hbox{such that} \ \lambda S-A  \,\,\hbox{isn't a Fredholm operator on}\, X \}$.

Comment: That's not working: $S=-1$

Comment: Can you give me more clarification

Comment: As I just realize, you probably meant to compare $\sigma(A+\lambda S)$ with $\sigma(A)$. Our expectation here clearly has to depend on what $S$ is (consider $S=1$, $S=-1$).

Comment: I want compare $\sigma_{e,S}(\lambda S- A)$ to $\sigma_{e,S}(A)$

Comment: The **title** of this question is horrible!!! :-)

Comment: I know what $\sigma_e$ is, but what is $\sigma_{e,S}$?

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture $\sigma_{e,S}(\lambda S- A)=\sigma_{e,S}(A) +  \lambda $ has to be wrong since you can choose for $A$ and $S$ the identity operator $I$ and get:

$$ \sigma_{e,I}(I) = \sigma(I) = \{1\} $$
$$ \sigma_{e,I}(\lambda I - I) = \sigma((\lambda -1)I) = \{\lambda -1\} $$

Maybe you conjecture should be $\sigma_{e,S}(\lambda S- A)=  \lambda -\sigma_{e,S}(A)$, but I really don't think this would hold in the general case.